# How to call multiple collections of Keen IO for a single graph?

Tags: javascript, keen-io

Can I call multiple collections of Keen IO for a single visualization graph?

Let's say I have a collection named `orders`:

```
{
  "order_number": "dfdfd2323",
  "order_price": 21.00,
}
```

And I have another collection named `adjustments`:

```
{
  "adjustment_id": "34ss3432",
  "adjustment_price": 2.00,
}
```

Now I want to display a bar graph which shows "total order price for every week" and "total adjustment price for every week". Weeks along x-axis and price on y-axis. Orders and adjustment price in different colors.

Can I make a nested call to Keen IO like this?

```
client.run(query1, function(){
.....
   client.run(query2, function(){
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[keen-js](https://github.com/keen/keen-js) supports passing an array of queries to `client.run()` as outlined in [this example](https://github.com/keen/keen-js/blob/v3.1.0/docs/visualization.md#combine-two-line-charts). Your setup could look something like:

```
var orders = new Keen.Query("sum", {
  eventCollection: "orders",
  targetProperty: "order_price",
  interval: "weekly",
  timeframe: "this_month"
});

var adjustments = new Keen.Query("sum", {
  eventCollection: "adjustments",
  targetProperty: "adjustment_price",
  interval: "weekly",
  timeframe: "this_month"
});

client.run([orderTotals,priceAdjustments],function(response) {
  var orderTotals = response[0].result;
  var adjustmentTotals = response[1].result;

  // code that draws the chart
}
```

The trick is understanding that the results of the queries are returned in an array in the same order as the array passed to `client.run()` via the `response` variable (or `this.data` if you prefer). The result of the first query in your array is returned as `response[0]`, the second `response[1]`, and so on and so forth. Likewise with `this.data`, you'd use `this.data[0]` and `this.data[1]`.

The chart shown in the example is a line chart, but could just as easily be configured to be displayed as a [bar chart](https://github.com/keen/keen-js/blob/v3.1.0/docs/visualization.md#bar-chart) via the `chartType` property.

Comment: @terrhorn ...thanks,that worked really well for me.
 I'd like to ask it out of curiosity, although i have managed to use google visualisations for drawing the chart,but do you think i could have used a keen api directly for drawing a chart within
     client.run(.....)
 method, from the response variable ?

Comment: @user3058470 -- Michelle Wetzler's sample shows you how to do just that.

Comment: callback will work with function(err, response). If query runs perfectly then null is returned in response parameter as a value of err.

Answer (score 4):

I thought it might also be helpful to share a code sample that results in visualization which combines queries from two collections, like this:

```
// use a variable to ensure timeframe & interval for both queries match
var interval = "daily"
var timeframe = "last_30_days"

var pageviews = new Keen.Query("count", { // first query
    eventCollection: "pageviews",
    interval: interval,
    timeframe: timeframe
});

var uniqueVisitors = new Keen.Query("count_unique", { // second query
    eventCollection: "pageviews",
    targetProperty: "uuid",
    interval: interval,
    timeframe: timeframe
});

var chart = Keen.Dataviz()
  .chartType("linechart")
  .chartOptions({
    hAxis: {
      format:'MMM d',
      gridlines:  {count: 12}
    }
  })
  .prepare();

client.run([pageviews, uniqueVisitors], function(response){ // run the queries

    var result1 = response[0].result  // data from first query
    var result2 = response[1].result  // data from second query
    var data = []  // place for combined results
    var i=0

    while (i < result1.length) {

        data[i]={ // format the data so it can be charted
            timeframe: result1[i]["timeframe"],
            value: [
                { category: "Pageviews", result: result1[i]["value"] },
                { category: "Visitors", result: result2[i]["value"] }
            ]
        }
        if (i == result1.length-1) { // chart the data
      chart
        .parseRawData({ result: data })
        .render();
        }
        i++;
    }
});
```

You can see an image of the chart here: https://github.com/keen/keen-js/blob/master/docs/visualization.md#combine-two-line-charts

Comment: --thanks for that. that works really well to make the graph with timeframe on the x-axis. Do you think I can create a similar graph against a property other than the timestamp. Say for instead of timeframe , I want to plot it against some other property like purchased_date.month , or against delivery_week ?